# How to handle dialogs in Angular component-based architecture

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I'm working on an application in Angular 1.5.
I stick to Component-based architecture (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)
and Input/Output flow described there.

Until now it worked fine, but now i need to open a child component as a dialog window and I'm stuck.

The architecture is fine when you render components tree down starting from main component. But i don't have an idea how get one of those children and display it as a dialog, and still use recommended Input/Output flow.

Do You know any pattern/library to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library would be angular material:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog

The pattern would have to be something like this:

```
// my-dialog.js
'use es6'
export default locals => ({
  locals, // will be bound to the controller instance!
  template:
`
<p>Something: <span>{{$ctrl.foo}}</span></p>
<md-button ng-click="$ctrl.onSave()">Save</md-button>
<md-button ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</md-button>
` ,
  bindToController: true,
  controllerAs: '$ctrl',
  controller: function($mdDialog, myService) {
    // this.foo = ..will be provided in locals as an input parameter..
    // this.onSave = () { ..will be provided as output parameter.. }
    this.cancel = () => {
      $mdDialog.cancel()
    }
  },
  clickOutsideToClose: true
})
```

Wich you would invoke from the parent component like this:

```
// main-component.js
'use es6'
import myDialog from './my-dialog'
..
$mdDialog.show(myDialog({
  foo: 'bar',
  onSave: () => { .. }
}))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: looks nice, but what about binding data from main component to the dialog?

Comment: Good point @JakubFilipczyk, a good trick is to turn the dialog into a factory and using the "locals" property to set parameters passed to by the main component (see modified example) cheers!